# bundle exec jekyll serve > Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files

Tags: ruby, jekyll

### Environment

- Windows 10
- ruby 3.0.0p0
- jekyll 4.2.0
- bundler

### Steps to get here

- installed ruby and jekyll using instructions: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/#installation-via-rubyinstaller
- cloned existing jekyll repository (uses minimal mistakes theme)
- successfully executed `bundle update` to update all the dependencies.
- manually installed `wdm`

Gemfile looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gemspec
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
```

### Issue

`jekyll serve` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` commands fail with the following error:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: C:/Users/linds/ueducateus-website/_config.yml
Source: C:/Users/linds/ueducateus-website
Destination: C:/Users/linds/ueducateus-website/_site
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
Generating...
Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
Conflict: The following destination is shared by multiple files.
The written file may end up with unexpected contents.
C:/Users/linds/ueducateus-website/_site/index.html
- index.html
- index.html
- index.html
- index.html
- index.html

done in 1.511 seconds.
Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/Users/linds/ueducateus-website'
------------------------------------------------
Jekyll 4.2.0 Please append `--trace` to the `serve` command
for any additional information or backtrace.
------------------------------------------------
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- webrick (LoadError)
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve/servlet.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:179:in `require_relative'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:179:in `setup'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:100:in `process'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:91:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `block in execute'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `each'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/command.rb:221:in `execute'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary/program.rb:44:in `go'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.4.0/lib/mercenary.rb:21:in `program'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/jekyll-4.2.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

### Additional

- Site builds successfully on Ubuntu 18.04, with Ruby 2.5.1 and Jekyll 4.0
- Unfortunately for handover, the site files need to be on Windows
- This issue could be related to https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt.github.io/issues/665
- Have run `jekyll serve --trace` but results are the same

Comment: One thing I noticed is that on Win you have Ruby 3.0 vs ruby 2.5 on Ubuntu (try a downgrade). The error says webrick is missing. Try installing it "gem install webrick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems webrick does not come bundled with ruby 3.0. Check this [jekyll github issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523).

> From
> https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2020/12/25/ruby-3-0-0-released/:
>
> The following libraries are no longer bundled gems or standard
> libraries. Install the corresponding gems to use these features.
>
> sdbm webrick net-telnet xmlrpc

You have two options

1. Downgrade to ruby 2.5 as you have on ubuntu OR
2. Add `gem "webrick"` in Gemfile.

Comment: Adding ```gem "webrick"``` has allowed the site to build -- thanks for that. It hasn't fixed the multiple address conflict but I recall seeing another issue on this subject that was caused by a category plugin -- thanks for your help on this :)

Comment: @lisadocs have you been able to solve the multiple address conflict ? I do have it when I use it on a Linux box, but not a Windows box, both after manual install of webrick. In my case it duplicate all posts in the psychoslave.github.io subdirectory… 

Comment: @psychoslave - TL;DR - I don't know. Basically the issue occured during handover of the site to another party. I provided the URL to this stackoverflow page to them and left them to it. I suspect they found *some* solution because the site has been updated since then.

Comment: Well, actually after a new investigation my issue above was due to a error from my part, as I had cloned twice the repository, once using only the `psychoslave.github.io` as parameter and moving it to `blog`and later when I forgot about it I cloned it with blog as second parameter. 